# "Wordpress" Video Player Width Issue

Tags: javascript, php, custom-controls, jwplayer

Hello"I buy theme and when i upload video width size half see in image please help me to solve this issue & i upload openload "Videos" and in theme have custom css & Java Script option

openload embed code:

```
<iframe src="https://openload.co/embed/QN8LwSy5tW8/The_Vampire_Diaries_S01E04_HDTV_%5BGlowGaze.Com%5D.mp4" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true">
```

[image]

code custom.css

```
.error-block {
    display: none;
    color: red
}

.jw-skin-seven .jw-overlay .jw-playlist-container {
    width: 400px;
    left: -20%
}

.jwplayer .jw-playlist {
    height: 250px
}

.jwplayer .jw-playlist .jw-option {
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left
}

.jw-playlist .jw-name {
    width: 30em !important
}

#content-embed iframe {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important
}

.bp-btn-like.active i {
    color: #79C142
}

.qtip {
    max-width: 320px;
}

.qtip .qtip-content {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 12px;
    overflow: visible
}

.qtip .qtip-content .f-desc {
    line-height: 1.3em !important;
    font-size: 12px !important
}

.qtip .qtip-title {
    margin-right: 60px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #71B43E;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0 0 12px;
    line-height: normal
}

.qtip .qtip-titlebar {
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important
}

.jtip-quality {
    top: 13px;
    right: 12px
}

#media-player {
    position: relative
}

.loading-film {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 180px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -90px
}

.content-kus {
    overflow: hidden
}

.content-kus div {
    margin: 0 auto !important
}

.cssload-center {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 70px;
    background: transparent
}

.cssload-2x {
    min-height: 100px
}

.cssload-3x {
    min-height: 160px
}

.cssload {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto
}

.cssload-2x .cssload {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px
}

.cssload-3x .cssload {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px
}

.cssload-3x .cssload span, .cssload-3x .cssload span:before, .cssload-3x .cssload span:after {
    border-width: 3px !important
}

.cssload * {
    box-sizing: content-box
}

.cssload span, .cssload span:before, .cssload span:after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent !important;
    border: 2px solid #79C142;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    display: inline-block
}

.cssload span {
    margin: -2px 0 0 -2px;
    animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -o-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite
}

.cssload span:before {
    content: "";
    margin: 5% 0 0 5%;
    height: 90% !important;
    width: 90% !important;
    animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -o-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite
}

.cssload span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 15%;
    height: 70% !important;
    width: 70% !important;
    animation: cssload-rotate 2300ms linear infinite;
    -o-animation: cssload-rotate 2300ms linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: cssload-rotate 2300ms linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: cssload-rotate 2300ms linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: cssload-rotate 2300ms linear infinite
}

.cssload-2x .cssload span::after, .cssload-3x .cssload span::after {
    top: 13%;
    left: 13%;
    height: 74% !important;
    width: 74% !important
}

@keyframes cssload-rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
    }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-rotate {
    100% {
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg)
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-rotate {
    100% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg)
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-rotate {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-rotate {
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg)
    }
}

.ps-container {
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    overflow: hidden !important
}

.ps-container.ps-active-x > .ps-scrollbar-x-rail, .ps-container.ps-active-y > .ps-scrollbar-y-rail {
    display: block
}

.ps-container.ps-in-scrolling {
    pointer-events: none
}

.ps-container.ps-in-scrolling.ps-x > .ps-scrollbar-x-rail {
    background-color: #eee;
    opacity: .9
}

.ps-container.ps-in-scrolling.ps-x > .ps-scrollbar-x-rail > .ps-scrollbar-x {
    background-color: #999
}

.ps-container.ps-in-scrolling.ps-y > .ps-scrollbar-y-rail {
    background-color: #eee;
    opacity: .9
}

.ps-container.ps-in-scrolling.ps-y > .ps-scrollbar-y-rail > .ps-scrollbar-y {
    background-color: #999
}

.ps-container > .ps-scrollbar-x-rail {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s linear, opacity .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color .2s linear, opacity .2s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color .2s linear, opacity .2s linear;
    transition: background-color .2s linear, opacity .2s linear;
    bottom: 3px;
    height: 8px
}

.ps-container > .ps-scrollbar-x-rail > .ps-scrollbar-x {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #aaa;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    transition: background-color .2s linear;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 8px
}

.ps-container > .ps-scrollbar-y-rail {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s linear, opacity .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color .2s linear, opacity .2s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color .2s linear, opacity .2s linear;
    transition: background-color .2s linear, opacity .2s linear;
    right: 3px;
    width: 6px
}

.ps-container > .ps-scrollbar-y-rail > .ps-scrollbar-y {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #555;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    transition: background-color .2s linear;
    right: 0;
    width: 6px
}

.ps-container:hover.ps-in-scrolling {
    pointer-events: none
}

.ps-container:hover.ps-in-scrolling.ps-x > .ps-scrollbar-x-rail {
    background-color: #eee;
    opacity: .9
}

.ps-container:hover.ps-in-scrolling.ps-x > .ps-scrollbar-x-rail > .ps-scrollbar-x {
    background-color: #999
}

.ps-container:hover.ps-in-scrolling.ps-y > .ps-scrollbar-y-rail {
    background-color: #888;
    opacity: .9
}

.ps-container:hover.ps-in-scrolling.ps-y > .ps-scrollbar-y-rail > .ps-scrollbar-y {
    background-color: #999
}

.ps-container:hover > .ps-scrollbar-x-rail, .ps-container:hover > .ps-scrollbar-y-rail {
    opacity: .6
}

.ps-container:hover > .ps-scrollbar-x-rail:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    opacity: .9
}

.ps-container:hover > .ps-scrollbar-x-rail:hover > .ps-scrollbar-x {
    background-color: #999
}

.ps-container:hover > .ps-scrollbar-y-rail:hover {
    background-color: #888;
    opacity: .9
}

.ps-container:hover > .ps-scrollbar-y-rail:hover > .ps-scrollbar-y {
    background-color: #999
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 800px) {
    .movieplay, .movieplay .wp-video .mejs-container {
        height: 300px !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 639px) {
    .movieplay, .movieplay .wp-video .mejs-container {
        height: 300px !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .movieplay, .movieplay .wp-video .mejs-container {
        height: 200px !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 899px) {
    .movieplay, .movieplay .wp-video .mejs-container {
        height: 400px !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .movieplay, .movieplay .wp-video .mejs-container {
        height: 500px !important;
    }
}

.movieplay .wp-video .mejs-container {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-height: 500px !important;
}

.movieplay .wp-video {
    width: 100% !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .qtip {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your question more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use videojs with bootstrap

Comment: i face only width problem no any other can you please solve this issue